# assembly instruction set for my processor

Tags: gcc, assembly, ubuntu-10.04, processor

Dear all, this is a simple question, I think. How do I find the instruction set for my processor? `proc/cpu` gives me (a vanilla cpu):

```
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 23
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     T6600  @ 2.20GHz
stepping        : 10
cpu MHz         : 1200.000
cache size      : 2048 KB
```

where do I find documentation about the instruction set for this? I'd like to get info to unlock `gcc`'s `.s` files to know how it's translating my code. Please accept my apologies if the question is not clear, I'll be happy to clarify. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.intel.com/products/processor/manuals/

You want the "Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer's Manual
Volume 2A: Instruction Set Reference, A-M" and the "Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer's Manual Volume 2B: Instruction Set Reference, N-Z".

Comment: Thank you! One other little piece of info: gcc seems to produce at&t syntax, is there a good equivalence sheet you know of?

Comment: Solved: gcc -S -masm=intel test.c