# Processor Architecture for Assembly

Tags: assembly

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [assembly instruction set for my processor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4070922/assembly-instruction-set-for-my-processor)

I am currently trying to program my own simple operating system. I am learning C++ and herd you need to know assembly in your processors code. I was wondering how you would find this information. When I google Intel Core i5-2435M architecture, it says 64 bit, when I want to know if it's x86 or something else. I found post that told you how to do so on windows, but I'm on a mac. Since I'm just a kid (11) who hopes to do this over the next 4 years, I hope you can help me figure this out. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

[x86, aka x86-32, aka IA-32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IA-32) is a 32-bit instruction set. Your Intel Core i5 processor runs the 64-bit version of that, called [x86-64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64), more specifically, [Intel 64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64#Intel_64). Note that processor architecture has little or nothing to do with the operating system your computer is running (Windows vs Mac vs ...).

All that said, you don't *really* need to know assembly in order to write C++, at least as a beginner.
Good on you for starting early, and good luck!